# While True statement and Pyg Latin

Tags: python

I wrote my very muddy (apologies) code for pyg latin (taken from Codeacademy).

It works ok, except I want to add a *While True*... statement so that if a user puts in a **number** or a **blank field** the input box re-appears until the condition is met

```
pyg='gy'
original=raw_input("please enter a word")
original_lc=original.lower()
first=original_lc[0]
rest=original_lc[1:len(original_lc)]

while True:
    if len(original) >0 and original.isalpha():
            print "Your word: " + original_lc
            if first in "aeiou":
                print "your pyglatin translation: " + original_lc + pyg
            else:
                print "your pyglatin translation: " + rest + first + pyg
                break


    else:
        print "You entered a blank field or a number. Please try again."
        break
```

I know this is incorrect. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the loop at the beginning, so that the user is asked for a new input if the first one is bad:

```
pyg='gy'
original=raw_input("please enter a word")

# keep asking for an input until the user inputs something valid
while len(original) == 0 or not original.isalpha():
    print "You entered a blank field or a number. Please try again."
    original=raw_input("please enter a word")

# at this point, the input should be valid
original_lc=original.lower()
first=original_lc[0]
rest=original_lc[1:len(original_lc)]


print "Your word: " + original_lc
if first in "aeiou":
    print "your pyglatin translation: " + original_lc + pyg
else:
    print "your pyglatin translation: " + rest + first + pyg
```

Comment: I'll take a look at this! I'm a bit slow! Thanks!

Comment: I understand your code; no doubt its way better. But what if I wanted to keep my original code with some tweaks. What will I have to do?

Comment: You can also replace the last `break` statement with `original=raw_input("please enter a word")`

Answer (score 0):

The call for `raw_input` should be inside your loop.

```
while True:

    pyg='gy'
    original=raw_input("please enter a word")
    original_lc=original.lower()
    first=original_lc[0]
    rest=original_lc[1:len(original_lc)]

    if len(original) >0 and original.isalpha():
            print "Your word: " + original_lc
            if first in "aeiou":
                print "your pyglatin translation: " + original_lc + pyg
            else:
                print "your pyglatin translation: " + rest + first + pyg
                break


    else:
        print "You entered a blank field or a number. Please try again."
        break
```

Comment: Ah I knew it was something stupid like that. Thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome! Remember, if you want to re-ask, you'll have to put the task inside the loop :)

Comment: when I copy and pasted, it indented the first "break" and it no longer looped.  Which brings me to my second question. Can you explain to me why indentation mattters for the break?

Comment: Well.. break escapes a loop. If the `break` statement is inside a condition, you'll keep looping until the condition is satisfied. If it's directly in the loop, the loop will break at the first try.